# Show different on the specific chars

Tags: ediff

Linux Mint 20, Emacs 27.2

I compare two files by **ediff**

Here result:

[image]

As you can see the **ediff** show different on the specific line.

But... I need to see different in the specific chars (**A** and **Z**).
I need to change background only on the different chars (**A** and **Z**). Not whole word.

Is  it possible?